# Can a pthread dispatched from native code call back into JNI?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, pthreads

Hypothetical: Calling C++ code from Java is relatively straightforward. As I understand it, the C++ code is executed in the same thread as the Java code calling it (correct me if I'm wrong). If the C++ code then starts a new *native* thread with `pthread_key_create()`, can this thread call back into Java through JNI? If so, how is this possible, since the code would then be executing in a pthread instead of a Java thread on the JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I understand it, the C++ code is executed in the same thread as the Java code calling it (correct me if I'm wrong)

The `JNIEnv` is attached to a thread, you cannot share a JNIEnv between threads. Your native functions all receive a `JNIEnv` as the first argument so it corresponds to the current Thread's `JNIEnv`.

> If the C++ code then starts a new native thread with pthread_key_create(), can this thread call back into Java through JNI?

All threads are Linux threads, scheduled by the kernel. They're usually started from managed code (using `Thread.start`), but they can also be created elsewhere and then attached to the `JavaVM`. For example, a thread started with `pthread_create` can be attached with the JNI `AttachCurrentThread` or `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon` functions. Until a thread is attached, it has no `JNIEnv`, and cannot make JNI calls.

> If so, how is this possible, since the code would then be executing in a pthread instead of a Java thread on the JVM?

See previous response too ;) (the first two sentences)

More infos [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've used `AttachCurrentThread` before but didn't understand why it was necessary. :)

Comment: @AndrewFarm No problem, JNI documentation is not user-friendly!

Comment: @AndrewFarm, The `AttachCurrentThread()` call creates a Java `Thread` instance.  The Java Runtime Environment requires that every Java thread must have a corresponding `Thread`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make upcalls to Java, a natively create thread should call first [AttachCurrentThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) or [AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon).

Comment: ...and don't forget to _detach_ the thread again if/when the Java function returns.  (Don't ask me how I know!)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this sample:

[image]

In this sample, you have a multi thread based code that calls Java code.

You can find full description here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-027/

And source code is available here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo027

I will not put all the codes here as it takes some space.

In fact, here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo032, 
you have more suitable sample for your. Where JVM calls C that calls JVM back invoking static method in Main class.

```
> java -Djava.library.path=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./lib -cp target recipeNo032.Main
I will call JVM
From JVM
I will call JVM
From JVM
I will call JVM
From JVM
I will call JVM
From JVM
I will call JVM
From JVM
I will call JVM
From JVM
```

Have fun with JNI.